# Como evitar que mouseenter acumule las veces que entra el mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como podría hacer para que mouseenter me deje de acumular las veces que entro en el tr.

me explico tengo una tabla que se llena automáticamente, lo que hago es que dependiendo el registro que se de clic habrá una opción de ver detalle 
ya tengo el código que hace la función pero lo que sucede es que cada vez que paso el mouse por encima va haciendo un conteo de las veces que paso

codigo HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tabla">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th>No. Cuenta</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btnEditContent1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" type="button" style="float: right;" onclick="actualizarDatos();">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></i>
                </button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="value : ${existen}">
            <tr class="_tr cursor-pointer amarilo">
                <td  th:text="${value.NoCuenta}" class="existentes" ></td>
                <td  th:text="${value.nombres}+' '+${value.paterno}+' '+${value.materno}" colspan="2" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="options success" style="display:none" th:id="${value.NoCuenta}">
                <td colspan="3" class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btnDetailEgresados1" th:value="${value.NoCuenta}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Ver Detalle
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
codigo JS
$(".amarilo").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){           
                var y=$(this).text().split("\n");
                var x=y[1].split("\t\t\t\t");
                console.log(x);
                if($(this).hasClass("success")){
                    $(this).removeClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo success").addClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo");
                    $("#"+x[1]).css("display","none");
                    y=null;
                    x=null;
                }else{
                    $(this).removeClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo").addClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo success");
                    $("#"+x[1]).css("display","table-row");
                    y=null;
                    x=null;
                }

            });
        });
```

asi es como se ve la tabla cuando se llena de manera dinamica
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando se da clic aparece la opcion de ver detalle
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que cuando paso varias veces el mouse por encima se van acumulando las veces que pase sobre el, y cuando doy clic me muestra todas las veces que pase y aveces muestra la opcion ver detalle y aveces no
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya estuve buscando e intentando con mouseenter y mouseover pero sigue siendo lo mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disculpa , pero no entiendo porque tiene que ser cuando el mouse pase por encima?.

intentaste directamente con el click??

```
codigo JS
$(".amarilo").on("click",function(){

   var y=$(this).text().split("\n");
                var x=y[1].split("\t\t\t\t");
                console.log(x);
                if($(this).hasClass("success")){
                    $(this).removeClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo success").addClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo");
                    $("#"+x[1]).css("display","none");
                    y=null;
                    x=null;
                }else{
                    $(this).removeClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo").addClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo success");
                    $("#"+x[1]).css("display","table-row");
                    y=null;
                    x=null;
                }



})
```

Comment: gracias me ayudo mucho

Comment: Genial me alegro, suerte.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas haciendo el mouseover para poder asignarle el evento al elemento.?
te recomiendo asignar el evento al crear el elemento, de no ser posible. te recomiendo usar `unbind`, para eliminar el evento que deseas usar, tu código quedaría algo así:

```
$(".amarilo").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).unbind('click'); // ELIMINAS CUALQUIER EVENTO "click" DEL ELEMENTO
            $(this).click(function(){ // ASIGNAS EL EVENTO "click" NUEVAMENTE           
                var y=$(this).text().split("\n");
                var x=y[1].split("\t\t\t\t");
                console.log(x);
                if($(this).hasClass("success")){
                    $(this).removeClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo success").addClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo");
                    $("#"+x[1]).css("display","none");
                    y=null;
                    x=null;
                }else{
                    $(this).removeClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo").addClass("_tr cursor-pointer amarilo success");
                    $("#"+x[1]).css("display","table-row");
                    y=null;
                    x=null;
                }

            });
        });
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: gracias fue de mucha ayuda